# Are there any Japanese words for "deport" and "incest" that sound similar enough for a bird brain to confuse?

Tags: japanese-language, monster-musume-no-iru-nichijou

In monster musume, Papi the Harpy confuses the word "deport" for "incest" a couple of times in the English subtitles. I could see "arrest" and "incest", but I am aware the work is not natively English, so jokes like that might come through a bit sideways. Is there a similar sounding pair of words for these two terms to explains Papi's malapropism?

Comment: Providing an example of an episode and time when this happens would be great, so we could hear the word being spoken.

Comment: @Killua It's in the first half of episode 2, although I'm not sure of the exact time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Japanese, "incest" is 近親相関 *kinshin soukan*, while "deport [to one's home country]" is 本国送還 *hongoku soukan*. These two terms are not similar enough for a reasonable human being to confuse. But for a birdbrain? I'd say it's plausible.

The *soukan* in the two items are unrelated; they just happen to be homophones.

(She makes this error twice in episode 2 - at 04:12 and 09:01.)